# MySQL Update Statement Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am updating my database with a form. I have it outputting the values of everything to check to make sure everyting is working correctly and it is, but when it adds it to the database everything is wrong. If the quantity is 20000 it just changes the quantity in the inventory to 1. I dont understand. I am still learning MySQL but this is irritating

```php
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    require("serverInfo.php");
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
        $company = $_POST['company'.$i];
        $size = $_POST['cardSize'.$i];

        if(isset($_POST['box'.$i])){
            echo $quantity . "<br / >";
            echo $size . "<br / >";
            echo $company . "<br / >";
            mysql_query("UPDATE `printRun` SET Quantity = '$quantity' AND Size = '$size'  where status='Open' AND Company = '$company'");
        }
    }
    mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: What are the "Types" set as? What character limit did you give them?

Comment: In other words, is the database columnn Quantity an integer or a character string (varchar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `printRun` SET Quantity = '$quantity', Size = '$size'  where status='Open' AND Company = '$company'");
```

Comment: that did indeed fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I will spare you the usual lecture about echoing and updating into your database unfiltered form data .... but your `update` syntax is incorrect. Try this instead (no `AND` in the column list)

> UPDATE `printRun` SET quantity='$quantity', size = '$size'  where status='Open' AND Company = '$company'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html

Comment: I would most certainly research MySQL prepared statements which will help you to maintain your code more effectively and ward off the most blatant of attacks such as SQL injection.